# Website Data Source is empty

Tags: rdlc, dataset

This is driving me insane. I am trying to get a basic Report to show with Report Viewer but cant get the DataSet to show in the Website Data Source window no matter what I do.

I created a dataset..picked the proc I want, etc. without any problems. I added my RDLC and tried adding a table that I can bind data to but the Windows that contains the Data Sources is empty.

Im using VS 2008. Is there anything im doing wrong? Ive followed some tutorials but cant get further due to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..figured it out after wasting 1 day on it.

As I said i am running VS 2008 and what I did was remove all the DLL references one by one until the window populated with some datasources. I found out a reference to Entity Spaces cause the problem. So I create the reports and when im down add back the reference. A pain but it now works.

Jeeesh.

Comment: you could have removed half of all your dll references each time until you have pinpointed the bad apple :) I did. That's because I only had 2.

Comment: Haoest that's called dichotomy. Xkcd need to make some comic about your idea.